# Applying mask to image breaks alignment

Tags: qt, layout, alignment, qml

Whenever I apply a mask to an image to make it circular, the alignment of UI elements breaks. The image is offset to the right by some number of pixels.

```
// main.qml
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Example")

    Page1Form {

    }
}

// Page1Form.qml
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1

Item {
   RowLayout {
        id: playerRowLayout

        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft

        Layout.fillWidth: true

        RoundedImage {
            id: displayImage

            width: 50
            height: 50

            Layout.preferredWidth: 50
            Layout.preferredHeight: 50

            source: "Images/DisplayPicture.jpeg"

            sourceSize.width: width
            sourceSize.height: height
        }

        Text {
            id: playerText
            text: qsTr("Hameer Abbasi (Pro)")
            font.family: "Source Sans Pro"
            font.pixelSize: 12
        }
    }
}

// RoundedImage.qml
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Image {
    id: img
    property bool rounded: true
    property bool adapt: true

    layer.enabled: rounded
    layer.effect: OpacityMask {
        maskSource: Rectangle {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            width: adapt ? img.width : Math.min(img.width, img.height)
            height: adapt ? img.height : Math.min(img.width, img.height)
            radius: Math.min(width, height)*0.5
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Misaligned]

When I change `RoundedImage` to `Image`, the misalignment disappears, like so:

[image: Image no longer rounded]

Also, when I add `anchors.fill: img` or `anchors.centerIn: img` to the `OpacityMask`, I get the following result (as you can see, the misalignment has not disappeared but just moved):

[image: Blank space in the wrong position]

The only thing that *does* seem to work is setting the `anchors.right: displayImage.left` on the textbox, but that somehow seems like a hack and I feel like I'm not doing something right somehow. Can someone help me figure out where the issue is and what the "proper" way to fix this would be?

Comment: I think you should not use `width` and `Layout.preferredWidth` (respective height) together. Consider setting the [`sourceRect`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#layer.sourceRect-prop) of your effect.

Comment: derM adding `layer.sourceRect: img.childrenRect` did not fix the issue. I'm not sure if that was what you intended.

Comment: Something like that. Just found the time to try it out myself. It is indeed mysterious... I don't know - might you drop the layout-stuff and go for anchoring and normal `Row`s instead?

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain you *why* this thing is happening. To me it looks like a bug.

Seemingly there is an easy workaround: Don't have the `Image` directly inside the `Layout`. Change the `RoundedImage.qml` to this:

```
// RoundedImage.qml
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Item {
    id: img
    property bool rounded: true
    property bool adapt: true
    property alias source: image.source
    property alias sourceSize: image.sourceSize
    Image {
        id: image

        width: img.width
        height: img.height
        layer.enabled: rounded
        layer.effect: OpacityMask {
            maskSource: Rectangle {
                width: adapt ? img.width : Math.min(img.width, img.height)
                height: adapt ? img.height : Math.min(img.width, img.height)
                radius: Math.min(width, height)*0.5
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the strange behavior is gone.